# Pandas - Rolling sum of time deltas (days) of activity in a specific period

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame of dates indicating the days when a machine was turned on and off.

```
        Date      Action
0 2019-09-25   Turned On
1 2019-10-10  Turned Off
2 2019-12-01   Turned On
3 2020-01-11  Turned Off
4 2020-01-23   Turned On
5 2020-03-28  Turned Off
6 2020-08-27   Turned On
7 2021-01-10  Turned Off
8 2021-02-17   Turned On
9 2021-06-30  Turned Off
```

I need to calculate how many days the machine spent turned on during a specified period, e.g. each quarter. For example, for the fourth quarter of 2019, it spent 40 days turned on:

- The period 2019-10-01 to 2019-10-10, plus
- The period 2019-12-01 to 2019-12-31.

The challenge is that the start and end of the quarter don't coincide with the entries in the DataFrame. One needs to work out that, in this example, the days in September and January need to be excluded.

Similarly, to calculate the days of activity in the first quarter of 2020, one needs to subtract the days in the interval 2019-12-01 to 2020-01-11 (rows 2 and 3) since they fall outside of 2020.

I have already attempted to take the difference between consecutive dates and take the sum of days that correspond to active intervals:

```
        Date   Direction     Days
0 2019-09-25   Turned On      NaT
1 2019-10-10  Turned Off  15 days
2 2019-12-01   Turned On  50 days
3 2020-01-11  Turned Off  41 days
4 2020-01-23   Turned On  12 days
5 2020-03-28  Turned Off  65 days
6 2020-08-27   Turned On 152 days
```

However, this fails to count intervals that started before each measurement period, and erroneously counts ones that start during the period but continue beyond it.

**Note:** I mention quarters as an example, but I also need to be able to work out the same information for arbitrary intervals. For example, for the 12 months after the first recorded activation, which in the example is 2019-09-25 to 2020-09-25, and then every 12 month period thereafter.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to add rows to the dataframe which mark the start of a new time period (quarter or month), create a new column for each date with its time period, then group by the quarter, and sum:

```
def time_online(df, t):
    if t in ['Q', 'M']:
        start = df['Date'].min().to_period(t).start_time
        end = df['Date'].max().to_period(t).start_time
    else:
        start = df['Date'].min()
        end = df['Date'].max()

    # some period-specific things- e.g. as we want the beginning date for each time period we have to use "QS" and "MS"
    if t == 'Q':
        end += pd.offsets.QuarterEnd(1)
        period = pd.date_range(start, end, freq="QS")
        name = "Quarter"
    elif t == 'M':
        end += pd.offsets.MonthEnd(1)
        period = pd.date_range(start, end, freq="MS")
        name = "Month"
    else:
        period = pd.date_range(start, end, freq=t)
        name = t

    df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame({'Date': period, 'Action' : 'New ' + name})]).sort_values(['Date', 'Action'])
    
    if t in ['Q', 'M']:
        df[name] = df['Date'].dt.to_period(t).dt.start_time # add time period start date as a column
    else:
        df[name] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: period[period <= x][-1])
    
    df['Current State'] = df['Action'].eq('Turned On').cumsum() - df['Action'].eq('Turned Off').cumsum()
    df['Active'] = df['Date'].shift(-1).diff()
    return df[df['Current State'].eq(1)].groupby(name).agg({'Active': 'sum'})

print(time_online(df, '90D'))
```

Output:

```
            Active
90D               
2019-09-25 38 days
2019-12-24 78 days
2020-03-23  5 days
2020-06-21 23 days
2020-09-19 90 days
2020-12-18 52 days
2021-03-18 90 days
2021-06-16 14 days
```

Assuming the data is like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
Date,Action
2019-09-25,Turned On
2019-10-10,Turned Off
2019-12-01,Turned On
2020-01-11,Turned Off
2020-01-23,Turned On
2020-03-28,Turned Off
2020-08-27,Turned On
2021-01-10,Turned Off
2021-02-17,Turned On
2021-06-30,Turned Off
"""),sep= ",", parse_dates=['Date'])
```

I've used the start of quarters and the start of months for the time periods here, but you could easily change it so it uses different time periods and/or starting dates (as in the example in your question of using the year following the start date).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time! Can you clarify, after doing `groupby`, how you would obtain the quarterly total of active days? The values appear to be all mixed in the output you've provided.

Comment: @stelioslogothetis I updated it so that is clearer

Comment: Thank you. Can you also clarify how to change it to use different starting dates? I attempted to simply change `start` but the reliance on date periods resets to the first of the month. For example, if I want 12 month intervals from the first entry, I still get results per calendar year instead.

Comment: @stelioslogothetis it depends upon the time format, but I'd play around with pd.date_range() and the [various frequency formats](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases)- e.g. `freq = '90D'` gives you a frequency of every 90 days

Comment: of course, quarters and months have different lengths, so things will drift

Comment: I understand, what I think is happening however is `df['Date'].dt.to_period(t).dt.start_time` causes the grouping&sum to be by calendar quarter/year rather than be based on the start date I specify.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254974/discussion-between-mark-and-stelioslogothetis).